# cuBLAS performance

Tags: performance, cuda, cublas

I use CUDA 5.0, and I want to compare matrix multiplication in C and cuBLAS. I already wrote a program in which matrix multiplication in C and cuBLAS both gave correct answers.

Now I want to compare their performance. For implementation in C, I used the `clock()`, but I found that cutil doesn't exist in CUDA 5.0, so I used `cudaEvent`. Both implementations use the same matrix, and in C, I just measured the time when C do the matrix multiplication, while in cuBLAS I began the measurement from `createhandle` till `destroyhandle`.

I got this result:
When C spends just 0.08ms, cuBLAS spend 59ms, and then I used `clock()` to measure time for cuBLAS, cuBLAS became faster than C. I don't know whether the method I used to measure time is correct. Why do `cudaevent` and `clock()` give different answers?

I use cuBLAS, cudaevent just following Nvidia's documentation. I'm really puzzled about how to measure time correctly.

Comment: Next time please spend some time to add proper punctuation, capitalization and formatting to your questions. That makes it a whole lot easier to read and follow.

Comment: How large are the matrices in question?

Comment: sorry, I'm in a hurry. I'll take care of writing next time, Thank you for your advice and help

Comment: I multiply (4536,233) and (233, 233).

Comment: You have a units problem. If your CPU were really taking 0.08ms for the size you say it would be producing around 6000 GFLOP/s, which is incredibly unlikely. Your CPU is probably taking 0.08 *seconds* to do the multiply, which would be 6 GFLOP/s, whcen your GPU is giving about 8 GFLOP/s.

Comment: When I use clock() to calculate time, it has a resolution of millisecond, I use the result to /CLOKS_PER_SEC, so the result is xxseconds, while in cudaevent the result is in xxms, and has a resolution of about half a microsecond, I mistake clock()'s resolution as its final result's unit. Thanks for you help. But can I use clock() to measure time for cublas?

Comment: you can try inserting cudaThreadsSynchronize() before clock() to see if it helps

Comment: Yes, most of the calls are. Only some of the routines which return a scalar value are blocking by default